# How to calculate annual return AR(1) coefficient from monthly return AR(1) coefficient?

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, finance, aggregation

I have a time-series data of $m$ months stock returns ($r_t$) that I assume satisfies the $AR(1)$ process:

$r_{t+1} = \rho r_t + \epsilon_{t+1}$  for  $t = 1,2,3,...,m-1$.

Now I cumulate every 12 months returns and get an annual returns($y_t$) series with size $n = m/12$.

Assuming $y_t$ follows an AR(1) as well:

$y_{t+1} = \phi y_t + \varepsilon_{t+1}$ for $ t = 1,2,3,...,n-1.$

What is the relation between $\rho$ and $\phi$? Does $\phi = \rho^{12}$ as in [this problem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250738/how-to-convert-annualized-standard-deviation-of-innovation-of-ar1-process-to-mon).

Comment: What do you get when you integrate the monthly equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AR(n) is not a stable class of models under aggregation. In your example, this assumption "Assuming  follows an AR(1) as well" is wrong and yearly data is not AR(1).

You can get an intuition for why it is wrong by writing down an example for aggregating monthly AR(1) into bimonthly AR(1).

$$x_t = ax_{t-1} + e_t$$
$$y_t = x_t + x_{t-1}$$
$$y_{t-1} = x_{t-2} + x_{t-3}$$
$$y_t = ax_{t-1} + e_t + ax_{t-2} + e_{t-1} = $$
$$ = a^2x_{t-2} + ae_{t-1} + e_t + a^2x_{t-3} + ae_{t-2} + e_{t-1} = $$
$$a^2y_{t-1} + u_t, u_t = ae_{t-1} + e_t + ae_{t-2} + e_{t-1}$$

This is not an AR(1) model because $u_t$ are not independent